# Remove the rotate icon in UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, ios6

is it possible to remove the little rotate icon in the UIImagePickerController that switches between the front & back cameras? This is for an app that won't goto the Apple Store, and it's only on one device. Anything i can do? I see that i can do this, but it removes the record button as well.

```
cameraUI.showsCameraControls = NO;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not, there is no direct way to turn off 1 particular camera control.

What you could do, is to do the following:

```
// Create a view that recreates the camera control functions you need.
// Your view will need to be able to set the following properties on camera UI
// cameraCaptureMode, cameraFlashMode (NOT cameraDevice, which is the control you want to disappear)

UIView* customOverlay = [..way to create your custom overlay..];
cameraUI.showsCameraControls = NO;
cameraUI.cameraOverlayView = customOverlay;
```

If you need to know how to create a custom overlay, it may be worth raising as another question.

Answer (score 1):

its all or nothing when it comes to showsCameraControls.  You need to either set showsCameraControls to NO and create your own cameraOverlay view, or roll your own camera using AVFoundation where again you'd need to create your own camera controls.